# If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy then $\left\{\frac{2x_n}{y_n}\right\}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, cauchy-sequences

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two Cauchy sequences in $S$, with $x_n,y_n\geq 10$. Prove that $z_n:=\left\{\frac{2x_n}{y_n}\right\}$ is also Cauchy in $S$. [It is assumed that $z_n\in S$.

> My proof:

Since $x_n, y_n$ are Cauchy in $S$, they are convergent in $S$ and thus bounded in $S$. Let $x_n$ converge to real number $L$ and $y_n$ converge to real number $M$.  Since $x_n, y_n$ are Cauchy, $\left|x_n-x_m\right|<\varepsilon$ for $N_1(\varepsilon)<n,m$ and $\left|y_n-_m\right|<\varepsilon$ for $N_2(\varepsilon)<n,m$. WLOG, suppose that $y_n > y_m$. Let $N:=\max\{N_1, N_2\}$, then
$$\begin{align}\left| \frac{2x_n}{y_n}-\frac{2x_m}{y_m}\right| & =\left|\frac{2x_ny_m-2x_my_n}{y_ny_m}\right| \\&\leq \left|\frac{x_ny_m-x_my_n}{5y_m}\right|\\&< \left|  x_n-x_m\frac{y_n}{y_m} \right|\\&\leq \underbrace{\left| x_n-x_m \right|}_{\text{since } \left| y_n-y_m\right| <\varepsilon\implies \frac{y_n}{y_m}\ge 1}\\ &<\varepsilon.\end{align}$$
Hence $z_n$ is Cauchy.

> End of proof.

But... I'm somewhat concerned that the argument under the underbrace is too handwavy. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: is it $a_n, b_n$ or $x_n ,y_n$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Fixed.

Comment: False. Let $S = \{10\}.$ Define $x_n,y_n = 10$ for all $n.$ Then $2x_n /y_n = 2 \not \in S$ for all $n.$

Comment: Well for starters your underbrace assertion is false if $y_n=1-\epsilon/2$ and $y_m=1$.

Comment: Presumably, $S$ is also complete, as zhw points out.

Comment: @AlexR. it is not given that $S$ is complete.

Comment: @zhw. it is given that $z_n\subseteq S$.

Comment: That wasn't given when I was writing my comment.

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Here's what I did now:

$2\left|\frac{x_ny_m-x_my_n}{y_my_n}\right|=2\left|\frac{(x_n-x_m)(y_m+y_n)-(x_ny_n+x_my_m)}{y_my_n}\right|<2\left| x_n-x_m \right|\left| y_m+y_n \right| < 4M\left| x_n-x_m \right| < 4M\varepsilon<\varepsilon'$ (where $M:=\sup\{y_n\}$ and $\varepsilon'=\frac{\varepsilon}{4M}$).

Comment: they are convergent in R, not necessarily in S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are Cauchy in $S$, they are also Cauchy in $\mathbb R$. Hence they are convergent in $\mathbb R$. Since $y_n\ge10$ we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\limits y_n = M\ge 10$, in particular $\lim_{n\to\infty}\limits y_n \not=0$. Hence $z_n=\frac{2x_n}{y_n}$ is convergent in $\mathbb R$, hence it is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$, hence Cauchy in $S$.